# Should I always nest selectors in other selectors when using sass?

Tags: sass, nested

My question is about nesting in sass or scss. It is a good thing from the readability perspective that we can nest selectors inside another selectors in sass but is it something that we must do? I am a little bit confused because when I run scss-lint, then I'm getting some errors nesting depth. I red a few articles and now I know that we should go deeper than nesting more than 3 rules one inside another.

So I have two questions:

1. Is there anything wrong if I will write my rules in sass just like this (without nesting):

   .my-class
       ...

Instead of writing like that:

```
header
    nav
        .myclass
```

2. Can you explain why is it necessary to nest in sass and what are the advantages of nesting? I know that it is good for overriding rules, but if I don't need to nest that deep? I will appreciate any answers or even links to some articles explaining my questions in more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually *avoid* nesting selectors in Sass if you don't have good reason to. See [Avoid Nested Selectors for more Modular CSS](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/avoid-nested-selectors-for-more-modular-css) and [Beware of Selector Nesting in Sass](https://www.sitepoint.com/beware-selector-nesting-sass/) for why you should be more selective about nesting.

Regarding your formatting, what you're doing is functionally equivalent to nesting, but you really shouldn't be formatting your line breaks and indentations to mimic nesting when that's not what your intent is.

```
header
  nav
    .myclass {...}
```

and

```
header {
  nav {
    .myclass {...}
  }
}
```

both produce:

```
header nav .myclass {...}
```

So even though `scss-lint` might be getting tripped up by your formatting, it's *probably* not something you want to be doing anyway. And if you simply aren't concerned with your nesting or selector depth, just [disable](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#configuration) or [override](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#disabling-linters-via-source) the linters.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't be writing my css selectors the sass way like you have shown in two top examples if I don't have any properties below header and nav selectors? Instead I should write it the same way as you show in the third example? I am not a native speaker but I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: Current conventions for managing CSS advise minimizing selector length (or nesting) because it creates unnecessary complexity, and often times makes your styling more fragile. BEM and other similar approaches address this with naming conventions, so instead of targeting `header nav .myclass`, you would give your class a unique semantic name and only target that. It might be `.myclass` or it could be `.header-nav__element-name`. Check out http://sass-guidelin.es and http://cssguidelin.es if you're interested in getting a handle on good CSS conventions.